# MailKit - ImapClient() .search() does not read EVERY emails C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, imap, mailkit

I'm using the MailKit client librairy to use their IMAP protocol in order to read my mails and search in it for a specific mail. It does work well for recent mail (less than a month and a half). But when I'm trying to search for an email that contains "myWordToSearch" from a long time (6 months old or stuff like that) it tells me that it does not exist, because it does not go that deep into the mails. Is there a way to retrieve/read **ALL** emails in order to filter them (like the search bar on gmail or stuff like that) ?

Here is my code :

```
               using (var client = new ImapClient())
               {
                        using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource())
                        {

                            client.Connect("imap." + provider , 993, true, cancel.Token);
                            client.Authenticate(myMail, myPassword, cancel.Token);
                            var inbox = client.Inbox;
                            inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly, cancel.Token);

                            var mail = (SearchQuery.SubjectContains(myWordToSearch)); 
                            foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(mail, cancel.Token))
                            {
                                  var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid, cancel.Token);
                            }
                         }
                }
```

Comment: Read them from where? Does your email provider return those emails through IMAP in the first place? Or do they have a 6-month restriction on searches to reduce their workload?

Comment: One of my email is @gmail.com (imap.gmail.com). Could they actually limit their IMAP workload by limiting the age of the mail ? 
I believe that, emails that are in the second page and + does not appear. 
But when you're using IMAP on your phone to get your mails, you get them all, or ?

Comment: You could download all the meta data and search yourself, but that’s a much more expensive operation.

Comment: You open `client.Inbox` so of course it doesn't search everything. It seaches the inbox. Try opening the "All mail" folder instead.